# Actionscript 3 PNGEncoder to PNG c#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, png, arrays, decode

Im using as3 PNGencoder (https://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/images/PNGEncoder.as?r=25)
Im sending it to my server and I recieve a huge Byte[6763]

im trying to get the Image with this:

```
        int Lenght = Request.RemainingLength;
        byte[] t = Request.ReadBytes(Request.RemainingLength);
        string k = Convert.ToBase64String(t);
        Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(t))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
```

But it always give me the error: Parameter not valid

I also tryed to Convert it to a base64 string and got this but also does it says its not a vailed image (k) and heres the base64 that K has after the Convert.ToBase64String():

```
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
```

So whats wrong? because I really doesnt have any idea! do i need to skip some bytes? or whats wrong with the base64? because it starts with gPNG what looks right...

Comment: Which api are you using to do the request? I don't remember seeing any request objects that give out a RemainingLength property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"do i need to skip some bytes? or whats wrong with the base64? because it starts with gPNG"`

Yes..!! You're very close to the answer and you should trust your "coding" instincts more. You should have experimented anyways. Also when in doubt check your "invalid image" bytes with a Hex Editor.

You base 64 string gives bytes like this: (in hex)
`00 00 1A 67 89 50 4E 47` which is `. . . g ‰ P N G`

If you remove the first four bytes: `00 00 1A 67` you have just `89 50 4E 47` onwards which gives a valid PNG header start bytes `‰PNG etc etc` (everything else is fine with your bytes).

***So whats causing it?***
 
A) I can only guess you're extracting the PNG from a larger set of bytes and somehow your grabbing from an offset of minus 4 of the actual image start bytes? Or reusing a Byte Array that already held those four bytes bytes and you're adding PNG bytes to it?

B) Your PHP or Server is editing the bytes? With some custom header bytes?

Anyway you just need a function for "clean-up before display" that just trims off the first four bytes..

[image]

Comment: Yeah thanks skipped the 4 bytes and it works perfect now :D. 
And true I need to trust my instincts more!